# How do we deal with questions about rumors and release dates?

Tags: discussion, scope

Today there were two questions about when the next episodes of a TV-show would be aired.

- https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/534/when-we-are-gonna-watch-the-end-of-kyle-xy
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/535/next-season-for-heroes
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/538/if-the-american-doctor-who-movie-is-made-will-it-be-a-reboot

On Scifi these questions were ruled off-topic, [as Mark Trapp said over there:](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates)

> I think they are two different types of questions, to be closed for different reasons:
>
> In terms of release date questions, there's a knowable date after which the question becomes useless. Those types of questions are a great example of something that should be closed as too localized, especially on a site like SciFi.SE: it's self-obviated on release date and there's no clear and present need for knowing the release date ahead of time (unlike, perhaps, knowing when PHP 6 or Python 3 is coming out, which can dictate how to proceed with a development project).
>
> In terms of rumor questions, I think your assessment is correct: they should be closed as not a real question, in line with Real Questions have Answers: rumor questions, by their nature, begin with the premise that the question answerers cannot speak with any authority about the subject matter; otherwise it wouldn't be a question about a rumor.

I'd propose we do the same here.

Comment: I'd include http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/538/if-the-american-doctor-who-movie-is-made-will-it-be-a-reboot in this discussion as well.

Answer (score 7):

I agree these questions will enter a localized state once the rumor/date is validated. This portion,

> They should be closed as not a real question, in line with Real Questions have Answers: rumor questions, by their nature, begin with the premise that the question answerers cannot speak with any authority about the subject matter; otherwise it wouldn't be a question about a rumor.

I agree with the above in full that these questions should be closed as "not a real question".