# Questions on if or when a movie or show will be released

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, votes

Are questions asking when or where something will be released on topic?

Are questions asking if something will be released or made on topic?

Multiple questions of the above types have mixed voting (some downvoted and VTC, others upvoted and close votes rejected by reviewers), despite a 6 year old meta question (with low participation and pre-graduation [How do we deal with questions about rumors and release dates?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171)). **Has the community changed its mind?**

Comment: Not dupe, asking for new community consensus.

Comment: Alright - fair point.

Comment: If you're going to make broad statements like "Multiple questions of the above have mixed voting" you need to support that with examples.

Comment: To what end? Point out questions you voted to close and the very similar one you decided to answer or voted to leave open on review? I didn't include unnecessary examples to avoid problems.

Comment: How are we supposed to address your concern if we don't have these examples? Part of your "job" as the person asking this Meta question is to explain it fully so that we can actually think about it and decide what to do. If you really want this to be productive, you have to show us what you are talking about.

Comment: Is x on topic? Is y on topic? Did they use to be off topic and now on topic? That seems pretty self explanatory.

Comment: You are explicitly claiming that there is inconsistency in the close voting but provide no evidence why you think that's true. That's the opposite of "explanatory".

Answer (score 9):

From the [Help Center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the following is shown as off topic:

> A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.

So in my opinion, questions about if or when something will be released are currently off topic.  However the community can change its mind about this, but that would be expressed through a meta-question.

Since you have revised the question to ask whether this is still the case - I would use this answer to vote for a continuation of the current policy that this is 'off topic'.

Comment: So what should be done about a question explicitly off topic then?

Comment: Lets not even get into the fact that it's a mod that asked a explicitly off topic question.

Comment: It should be closed.  Don't beat about the bush - if there is a specific question that you want to ask about, ask about it rather than alluding to something you clearly already know the answer to.

Comment: Mixed voting, as in some of these types of questions get downvotes and closed, others get upvoted. No consistency in how they are handled by community and moderation teams.

Comment: And by the way, moderators are allowed to make a mistake of judgement - its not a crime to ask an off-topic question, but it should be closed just like any others.

Comment: The community can vote (up or down or close) as it wishes.  Moderators should attempt to be consistent in how they apply the community standards and stack-exchange policies, but the community can do as it pleases, how would you suggest we do otherwise?

Comment: This question https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62479/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-cde

Comment: I would admit this is a grey area.  Really we're intending to clamp down on "when is season x of series y going to air' ... rather than a question posing a potentially interesting question - i'd want to see answers that attempt to properly analyze or provide quotes from producers etc.

Comment: And before you accuse me of bias towards a fellow moderator, please note that I have a no-closer personal relationship with the moderator in question than I do with you.  I would have just the same opinion if the question were asked by anyone.  Its a grey area, but the spirit of the on/off topic of this kind of question is to clamp down on simple "when is this due to release" questions.

Comment: And before you accuse me of anything, how about you don't?

Comment: What have I accused you of?  I'm merely pre-emptively pointing out that I'm aware that I could be accused of that.

Comment: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2906/questions-on-if-or-when-a-movie-or-show-will-be-released/2907?noredirect=1#comment11038_2907

Comment: Since when do the answers dictate on-topic-ness?

Comment: The question is not asking for rumours or dates.  Whatever ....if you think its off topic and damaging to the quality of questions on the site -  put your close vote in and let the community decide.  In situations that I think are a grey area I generally hesitate to wield the super-close-vote that I have.

Comment: I don't see a difference between When or If. That's why i asked if each type makes a difference, or if the community decided they are now on topic.  Like you said, express it through a meta question.

Comment: The question even uses rumors as it's basis  `even though it was rumored that ABC ordered a pilot`. When is asking if a show is being created asking for rumors, only when it says "please give me rumors?"

Comment: There were official announcement about it which you might already know and if you really read it as "please give me rumors?" then try to read it again or feel free to suggest better wording where you can understand the main question well.

Comment: You don't reference said official announcement.

Comment: I don't see anything in the said question that makes us think that OP is asking fro release dates.